# Why is my listener not being called within the recycler view adapter?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, listener, listadapter

I have a RecyclerView with a list of players. I want to call my listener when a player is clicked. I have logs for when a player is clicked and another where the listener is implemented. The log where the listener is implemented is not printing out. Does anyone see anything wrong?

TeamSelectionAdapter:

```
class TeamSelectionAdapter internal constructor(
        context: Context,
        val listener: TeamSelectionAdapterListener
) : ListAdapter<Player, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(DIFF_CALLBACK) {
    private val inflater: LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)

    interface TeamSelectionAdapterListener {
        fun onPlayerTouched(currentPlayer: Player)
    }

    inner class TeamViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        private val playerCard = itemView.findViewById<MaterialCardView>(R.id.player_card)

        fun bind(player: Player){

            playerCard.setOnClickListener {
                logDebug("Clicked! Now to call listener")
                listener.onPlayerTouched(player)
            }

        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = currentList.size

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        val playerItemView: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.playercard_draggable, parent, false)
        return TeamViewHolder(playerItemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        (holder as TeamViewHolder).bind(getItem(position))
    }

    internal fun setTeams(playerList: List<Player>){
       submitList(playerList)
    }

    companion object {
        val TAG = PlayerListAdapter::class.java.toString()

        private val DIFF_CALLBACK = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Player>() {
            override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Player, newItem: Player): Boolean {
                return oldItem == newItem
            }

            override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Player, newItem: Player): Boolean {
                return oldItem.id == newItem.id
            }

        }
    }

}
```

TeamFragment:

```
class TeamCardFragment: BaseFragment() {

    private lateinit var teamBackgroundImage: ImageView
    private lateinit var teamRecyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var teamSelectionAdapter: TeamSelectionAdapter
    private var teamNumber: Int = -1
    private var isDropped: Boolean = false

    override fun onInflate(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onInflate(context, attrs, savedInstanceState)

        context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.TeamSelection).apply {
            teamNumber = getInt(R.styleable.TeamSelection_teamNumber, -1)
            logDebug("teamNumber: $teamNumber")
            recycle()
        }

    }


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        teamSelectionAdapter = TeamSelectionAdapter(requireContext(), object : TeamSelectionAdapter.TeamSelectionAdapterListener {
            override fun onPlayerTouched(currentPlayer: Player) {
                Log.d("******", "****player selected: $currentPlayer")
                playerViewModel.setSelectedPlayerId(currentPlayer.playerId)
            }
        })
    }


    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.team_card, container, false)


        teamBackgroundImage = view.findViewById(R.id.teamBackground)
        teamBackgroundImage.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.color_on_secondary,null))
        teamBackgroundImage.background.alpha = 50
        teamRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.player_card_recyclerView)

        teamRecyclerView.adapter = teamSelectionAdapter
        teamRecyclerView.setOnDragListener { v, event ->
            val viewSource = event.localState as View
            val viewId = v.id
            when(event.action){
            DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED -> {
                when(viewId){
                    teamRecyclerView.id -> {
                        logDebug("team $teamNumber drag entered")
                    }
                }
            }
            DragEvent.ACTION_DROP -> {
                isDropped = true
                when(viewId){
                    teamRecyclerView.id -> {
                        playerViewModel.selectedPlayer.value?.let{
                            playerViewModel.updatePlayerTeam(teamNumber,it.playerId)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            }
            true
        }



        playerViewModel.allPlayers.reobserve(this){
            logDebug("players changed: $it")
            it?.let{ playerList ->
                    val teamPlayers = playerList.filter { player -> player.team == teamNumber  }
                    teamSelectionAdapter.setTeams(teamPlayers)
            }

        }



        return view
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you drag the whole recyclerview or just a row? if it's only a row I think you need to change your id to R.id.player_card instead of teamRecyclerView.id

Comment: `TeamSelectionAdapter(requireContext(), object : TeamSelectionAdapter.TeamSelectionAdapterListener `, you should use `this` as a reference instead object